# Syntax error in function to shift array by k

Tags: syntax-error, ocaml

I'm trying to shift array by `k` to left.
Here's my code. But I'm getting compile error on `shifted;;` line.

```
let shift_left (arr: array) (kk: int) =
    let size = Array.length arr in
        let k = kk mod size in
    let shifted = Array.make size 0 in

    for i = 0 to size - 1 do
        if i < k
        then (shifted.(size - k + i) <- arr.(i))
        else (shifted.(i-k) <- arr.(i))
    done

    shifted;;


let arr = [| 1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9; 10 |];;
let shifted = shift arr 4;;

Array.iter print_int arr;
print_string "\n";;

Array.iter print_int shifted;
print_string "\n";;
```

Here is what I getting in terminal:

```
$ ocamlc -o shift shift.ml

File "shift.ml", line 11, characters 1-8:
Error: Syntax error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two compiler errors here:

1. A syntax error between `done` and `shifted`. Because line breaks are not significant in OCaml, it will be parsed as `done shifted;;`, which looks like a function application, but is not valid since `done` is a keyword, not an identifier that might refer to a function. Use the sequence operator, `;`, to evaluate two expressions in sequence.
2. A type error: `array` is not a concrete type, it takes a type parameter specifying the type of value it contains. It should be `int array` in this case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it really helped me! But for 2nd point - i totally removed types in function definition and now all works fine. Coz they inferred automatically.. but maybe its bad code style?

Comment: Yeah, they'll be inferred. It's good practice to at least annotate the types of the functions you export from a module, but you'll usually do that in an interface file. Otherwise it's a good idea to add types if you get a type error you can't quite figure out, as it gives the compiler more information to work with and yields more informative error messages.